# Open websites in new tab from launcher

Tags: google-chrome, launcher

I would like to have launcher shortcuts that open websites in the same Google Chrome window that I'm already using. If I create shortcuts by using the More Tools --> Create shortcut function it will open a new window with a blank tab and the website in another tab.

I tried using different commands in the .desktop files like

```
Exec=google-chrome -new-tab [website]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Mate:

1. Create a text file with any editor a put the following content on it:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Open Ask Ubuntu
   Type=Link
   URL=https://www.askubuntu.com/
   Icon=text-html
   ```
2. Save the file with the extension `.desktop` (e.g. Ask Ubuntu.desktop)
3. Open your shortcut and the URL of it will be loaded on the current window or instance of Google Chrome that you already have running.

If this doesn't work, try with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=google-chrome https://www.askubuntu.com
Name=Ask Ubuntu
Comment=Open Ask Ubuntu in Google Chrome
Icon=ask-ubuntu
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Keywords=Network;AskUbuntu;
Name[en_US]=AskUbuntu
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works when I open the shortcut from the file browser, but when open it from the launcher it still opens a new window..

Comment: Which launcher are you using?

Comment: The default Ubuntu one .. Unity I guess

Comment: I added to my answer another option for you to try, let me know if it works. Right now I don't have a Unity launcher to test it.

Comment: Same result, works in file browser but not in launcher

Answer (score 0):

I did it by copying `google-chrome.desktop` file and modifying it:

```
    cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/askubuntu.desktop
    chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/askubuntu.desktop

    vim.tiny ~/.local/share/applications/askubuntu.desktop
```

Changing only **Name** and **Exec** parameters:

```
    Name=Askubuntu in Google Chrome

    Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U askubuntu.com
```